# Find all rows in PSQL query that adds upto next possible sum above target

Tags: sql, postgresql

Like in below if my target_sum is

- 5 it should return id 1
- 8 then it should return id 1 and 2
- 13 then it should return id 1, 2 and 3

Basically my query should return the next possible sum above my target_sum how to modify below query

| id | marks |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 9 |

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
               SUM(marks) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS cum_sum
        FROM students
    ) t
    WHERE cum_sum <= target_sum
    ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one to the `cum_sum` and use `LAG`to pass it in the next row

**Data**

```
id|marks|cum_sum|cum_sum_lag|
--+-----+-------+-----------+
 1|    5|      5|          0|
 2|    7|     12|          6|
 3|    6|     18|         13|
 4|    9|     27|         19|
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, marks, cum_sum,
       lag(cum_sum+1,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS cum_sum_lag
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
               SUM(marks) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS cum_sum
        FROM students
    )  t1
) t2
WHERE cum_sum_lag <= :target_sum
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: I think it could be done without adding one as well as we are just deferring sum of first row to start from next right ?

Comment: Well without adding one you have to use `cum_sum < target_sum` (not `<=`) @sahil

Answer (score 0):

This statement does the trick.

```sql
select id, marks
from (
  select *,
    lag(sum,1,0) over (order by id) lag_sum
  from (
    select 
      *,
      sum(marks) over (order by id) sum
    from demo
  ) x 
) y
where lag_sum < 8 -- <-- target sum goes here
order by id;
```

It uses the [`lag` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) to access the `sum` of the previous row.

[DB fiddle to play with the query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ghCzv7jm7HvJt9xivqYEmD/1).

Comment: Pls check the result for `5` where only one row is expected. You need to use either `<` or subtract one es proposed on other answer;)

Comment: correct. Fixed it.